# Bug: crossrider extension adds images to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, crossrider

The extension appears to be doing a "clipboard injection" of the Company's logo used somewhere in the extension DOM injections. Several users have noticed that after loading the extension the Company's logo suddenly appears in their life, often on their clipboard.

Here is one example:
2 times now that I've emailed someone, I've left the gmail window, to go find something I wanted to copy and paste (in this case, the command to run in the console). Both times, upon returning, when I hit paste, I get 2 quite large Company's logos... It's quite unsettling. How can I take care of the this bug?

Comment: The title states its a bug, so I need a way to disable the extension from intruding the user's clipboard

Comment: Where can I find this extension (for review of source code)? If you're a user of the extension, then this question belongs to http://superuser.com/. If you're a developer of this add-on, then SO is the right place.

Answer (score 1):

edit for clarity: CrossRider is not an extension per itself, it is a development framework used by some developers to create *cross browser* extensions. So you need to find which extension is causing this behavior exactly.

original answer:
This is sometimes called clipboard hijacking or copy/paste hijacking. It can be done by websites in js or by extensions. It's often used by websites to add a trackback link to the source of the content. SEO tactics maskerading as source attribution.

What they do is they register to the clipboard events and replace the selected text with an augmented copy containing their text, link or image. It can go further and sends back the selected text to their server for analytics purposes.

In Firefox you can disable [dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled) preference to control what sites have access to.

Answer (score 1):

@Jhene, as @Yolanda had mentioned, Crossrider is a development framework that lets developers build cross-browser extensions with a simple JavaScript API.

What you see is an extension that was probably developed by the Crossrider framework and not the framework behavior itself whatsoever.

If you could please send more details to our support (support@crossrider.com), with more information, such as the extension name and a screenshot of the logos you are seeing pasted, so we can take care of the issue you are experiencing.

Disclosure: I'm a Crossrider employee